# How to check Current device time when app is in Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am working on a app which need to check time after every minute when the app is in the background.  I want to match current time with specific time, and if time matches then the app should show an alert (when app is in background).

Comment: I have researched a lot and find the two solutions only local or push notifications Is there any other way.......

Comment: No not really, Apple has restricted the way apps can run in the backgroud. They want to minimize the number of apps that run to save battery. Thus on VOIP, music, location and accessory app are allowed to run.

Comment: That is exactly a scenario for local notifications. And if you want to  show notification later when the app is back at foreground, store the last time it entered background, look for missed notifications and show them.

Comment: thanks for replying but if a person has to take medicine at 10 am 12pm then I have to show notification at exact time 10 am and 12 pm not after not before

Comment: @user2156767 this is what a local notification is for, you can set the fireDate property to whatever time you need

Answer (score 1):

You set a Local Notification and even the App is dead after going to background, the local notification will pop up. As in your example it will tell the user "Time to take your medicament" and if the user choose the "View Details" button, your app will be fired from the iOS

Comment: thanks for reply but if user did not tap the button I need to update date and time accordingly

Comment: If you need to communicate with the user or better say if you need definitly user interaction, you can not use Local Messages. But in that case you can use my second answer below. It will function definitly.

Answer (score 0):

Another method how can you do this is to trick the ios (Apple :-) )

Apple allows you to stay in background without beeing killed if you do some specific tasks, such as Location

So what you can do is
in the info.plist add "Required background modes" and value Location

Info here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Than Set up a CLLocationManager for scanning the location and obey the Apples advice and make it not very accurate (battery life saving)

Setup a timer and in the timer routine check the location (that saves the apps life) and than do whatever you want to do ...

This should also work.